# Duplicate textbox in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, duplicate, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I see the "Duplicate" button only for the slides. How do I find it for the textbox? Inkscape, for instance, has such option to create the new object right at the same place as the source object. This is what I am asking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to duplicate a textbox on a slide, just select it, then copy and paste. If you paste it into a different slide it will have the same properties as on the original (positioning, size, etc.); if you paste it back into the original slide it will be offset slightly so that it doesn't completely overlap the original. No duplicate button because this feature is covered by copy/paste.

Comment: This is a right answer for the question in the original edition but I want something more (see the edit).

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have managed to do this

1. Copy & Paste
2. Select all duplicates
3. Use "Size and Position" in the cotnext menu.
4. Assign the same position (e.g. 10,10). This will collect all the objects in one place.
5. Drag them wherever you want.

which is quite satisfactory for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Select the shape (or click within a text box then press ESC to select it)
Press Ctrl+D to duplicate it.
Press the up arrow twice, left arrow twice.
It's now aligned with the original

If you need more than one duplicate, keep pressing Ctrl+D after the above.
Further dupes will be aligned with the first.